# Take a picture on background service android (Camera and Camera2)

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-developer-api

I want to take a picture each minute without start camera activity and save it on the device storage, how I can start and use the camera on a background service...

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Post the code you already have

Comment: I have the code to to take the picture and save it, but I dont know how to use that on a background service because I have to use an AutoFitTextureView, if I create all in a background service the AutoFitTextureView element not exist.

mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture);

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Service
Make connection to camera
You can make Tier that will make photo from some time.

```
    public class CameraPhoto extends Service {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(), 0, 1800000); //тикаем каждые 30 мinute без задержки 
        }
        //задача для таймера

        class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {
            public void run() {
//Here write what you want do . You can call method here, or make manipulation with camera
                }
            }
```